# To make "\" to category 12, why should convert it to category 13 in TeX？

Tags: tex-core, strings, catcodes

Exercise 7.5 on page 40 of **The TeXbook** asks to make `\` to category 12. The answer of this question is

```
{\catcode‘/=0 \catcode‘\\=13 /message{/string\}}
```

Why should assign the `\` to 13 not 12?

The explaination of this answer is

> (The “null control sequence” that you get when there are no tokens between \csname and \endcsname is not a solution to this exercise, because \string converts it to ‘\csname\endcsname’. There is, however, another solution: If TEX’s \escapechar parameter—which will be explained in one of the next dangerous bends—is negative or greater than 255, then ‘\string\’ works.)

1. > The “null control sequence” that you get when there are no tokens between \csname and \endcsname is not a solution to this exercise

What does this mean?

2. > If TEX’s \escapechar parameter—which will be explained in one of the next dangerous bends—is negative or greater than 255, then ‘\string\’ works.)

What does this mean?

Very difficult to understand them.

Comment: The _question_ is about the effect of `\string` on active chars ...

Comment: @JosephWright So can this way make `\ ` to be category 12? I don't think so.

Comment: the result of `\string\ ` is to make a character token with a catcode 12 \  it does not change the `\catcode` settings for new characters that are read.  Just as `\string~` makes a catcode12 token `~` it does not change `\catcode\`\~` which is still 13.

Comment: as Joseph says he uses 13 there as the question is about active characters but you could use anything else that makes a token, so 11 or simply 12 would also work.

Comment: Okay. How about the another two questions in the post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation is in the solution of the exercise. Knuth suggests to try

```
\message{\string~}
\message{\string\~}
```

to see that the result is, respectively `~` and `\~`. The fact that you get these characters in the output of `\message`, which does *full* expansion on the tokens it is fed with, means that these characters have “printable category code”, in this case precisely 12.

If you try `\message{\string\}` you won't go very far because `\}` becomes a single token and not a closing brace.

However, the example with `~` which is normally an active character, tells you that you can make the backslash active (in a group, so it will resume its standard behavior at group end) and “stringify” it:

```
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=\active /message{/string\}}
```

Of course if you want a “usable” backslash with category code 12, you need to define a macro for it:

```
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=\active /xdef/bschar{/string\}}
```

Alternatively (and you may want to investigate how this works)

```
\begingroup\lccode`~=`\\ \lowercase{\endgroup\edef\bschar{\string~}}
```

Another solution (the one hinted at by Knuth) is

```
{\escapechar=-1 \xdef\bschar{\string\\}}
```

All three ways end up in `\bschar` expanding to a backaslash with category code 12.

You might also do

```
\chardef\bschar=`\\
```

but this would make `\bschar` into an unexpandable token that *prints* a backslash (assuming the font has a backslash at slot 92).

Is it necessary to use category code 13? Not at all. All of the following will show `\` on the console:

```
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=1 /message{/string\}}
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=2 /message{/string\}}
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=3 /message{/string\}}
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=4 /message{/string\}}
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=6 /message{/string\}}
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=7 /message{/string\}}
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=8 /message{/string\}}
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=11 /message{/string \}}
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=12 /message{/string\}}
{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=13 /message{/string\}}
```

Note the (mandatory) space in the case of catcode 11. A space can be used also in the other cases, of course.

Comment: May you help me to explain the `\active` here? Does it equal to `13`?

Comment: @Y.zeng A `\chardef` or `\mathchardef` token can be used in all situations in which the syntax requires a `<number>`. Plain TeX and LaTeX do `\chardef\active=13`.

Comment: So, what is the meaning of ``\catcode`\\=\active``?

Comment: @Y.zeng The same as ``\catcode`\\=13 ``

Comment: But you have assigned `/` to category 0, so I think you should change ``\catcode`\\=\active`` to ``/catcode`/\=/active``, why not?

Comment: @Y.zeng Because the backslash still has category code 0 unti the catcode assignment has been finalized. You can certainly say ``/catcode`/\=/active``, though.

Comment: Why doesn't ``{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=11 /message{/string\}}`` work well? Assigned `\ ` to category 11 to make `\ ` just as a character.

Comment: @Y.zeng You're trying to use the control sequence whose name is ``string\`` (because of the rules for forming control sequences). It would work with a space between `/string` and ``\``. I added something at the end.

Comment: Why does need add a space between `/string` and ``\``?

Comment: @Y.zeng I've already told you why.

Comment: When ``\catcode`\\=12``, no need to add space, but ``\catcode`\\=11``, there is need to add. Is it because the latter ``string\`` is 7 characters of   category 11, so it is treated as a whole? If it is so, why doesn't ``{\catcode`/=0 \catcode`\\=11 /message{/string{\}}}`` work?

Comment: @Y.zeng That's it. But with `\string{\}` you're making `\string` act on `{` and you end up with ``{\`` being shown (plus an error for the unbalanced `}`).

Comment: Why does `\string` act on `{`, witch is a beginning of a group?

Comment: @Y.zeng `\string` acts on the next token; ``{\}`, in your case is three tokens.

Comment: Why doesn't `\string` eat space following it?

Comment: @Y.zeng What space? In ``\string \`` there is *no* space after tokens are formed.

Comment: Okay. I know now. Thanks.